# Curl verbose supress certain details

Tags: linux, http, unix, curl

I am writing a shell script in which i save curl output to a variable. I have certains attributes in my url which I dont want to be printed in logs. But I want to print verbose output of curl to logs so I can see the complete flow of my call.

my current command

```
STATUSCODE=$(curl -v -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" "$API$TOKEN")
```

due to above command it prints verbose output but print token in logs which I want it to supress.

Comment: Use `grep` to filter the output.

Comment: or `egrep -v 'ignoreStr1|ingoreStr2|ignoreStr3|....'` to skip parts of the output. Good luck.

Comment: thanks. I ll try this.